VSCode does not detect installed python libraries and modules
I have a Python project open in VSCode that operates various libraries and it's composed of different modules.
Venv is activated, and all libraries are installed in venv.

But still VSCode does not see them installed and underlines them. Same issue with modules (other python files) that I try to import. Paths to modules are correct and modules exist.

The interpreter was chosen correctly:

Can you suggest the solution

Have you tried restarting VSC?

Sure. Still same result

Is it a problem when you run the code (as in, an error saying the necessary libraries are not installed) or is it just VS Code not recognizing the installed libraries?

Both. VSC underlines unrecognized libraries and modules and of course it causes the error if I run the code

What error does it throw? Have you checked if the version of the library you installed is compatible with your venv (Python v)?

"aiogram": Unknown word.
I have installed aiogram 3.12.0 and it's fully compatible with my interpreter version Python 3.11.4

I still think it's caused by the wrong python interpreter, if you choose the right interpreter with the python package installed and run the code, it won't give an error report. Please check your python interpreter and ensure that the environment has been actived. You could use command pip list to check whether the python package has been installed in the current environment.

This is what pip list shows
pip list                                                                                                                                                          ─╯
Package           Version

aiofiles          23.2.1
aiogram           3.12.0
aiohappyeyeballs  2.4.0
aiohttp           3.10.5
aiosignal         1.3.1
annotated-types   0.7.0
attrs             24.2.0
certifi           2024.7.4
frozenlist        1.4.1
idna              3.8
magic-filter      1.0.12
multidict         6.0.5
pip               24.2

If python will not give the error report when you run the python script, you could try to set "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["path/to/your/package"] to achieve it. Or you could try to set the PYTHONPATH of environment variable.

i'm faced similar issue before and There are a few ways to achieve this, but i assume the cleanest/simplest of which is probably using a custom .vscode settings.json.

Let's says you have a workspace with such structures,

.
└── your_workspace/
    ├── folder_a
    ├── folder_b/
    │   └── foo/
    │       └── bar
    └── python_folder/
        ├── main.py
        └── requirements.txt


Then you want to setup venv inside python_folder. So you open up the terminal and run these command,

# initialize venv inside python_folder
your_workspace# python3 -m venv ./python_folder/venv


Setup your settings.json,

# create directory and settings.json file
your_workspace# mkdir .vscode
your_workspace# touch .vscode/settings.json


Put these configuration inside settings.json,

{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "./python_folder/venv/bin/python",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
}


You will have an updated workspace structures like so,

.
└── your_workspace/
    ├── folder_a
    ├── folder_b/
    │   └── foo/
    │       └── bar
    ├── folder_python/
    │   ├── main.py
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   └── venv/
    │       ├── bin/
    │       │   ├── activate
    │       │   ├── pyhton3
    │       │   └── ...
    │       └── ...
    └── .vscode/
        └── settings.json

After that, you might want to reload your vscode windows. You can open an integrated terminal and see something like this

Finally, now you can install packages into venv in the python_folder in any directories inside the workspace
your_workspace# pip3 install --upgrade -r ./python_folder/requirements.txt

Your vscode will automaticaly recognize the venv everytime you open vscode

refer to vscode python environments
